# GARCH model in pymc3: how to loop over random variables?

Tags: pymc, pymc3

I'm attempting to implement a GARCH model in pymc3, along the lines of [this example](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/stochastic_volatility/). For this I attempted to implement a GARCH(1, 1) distribution as follows

```
import pymc3 as pm
from pymc3.distributions import Continuous, Normal

class GARCH(Continuous):
    def __init__(self, alpha_0=None, alpha_1=None, beta_1=None, sigma_0=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GARCH, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.alpha_0 = alpha_0
        self.alpha_1 = alpha_1
        self.beta_1 = beta_1
        self.sigma_0 = sigma_0
        self.mean = 0

    def logp(self, values):
        sigma = self.sigma_0
        alpha_0 = self.alpha_0
        alpha_1 = self.alpha_1
        beta_1 = self.beta_1

        x_prev = values[0]
        _logp = Normal.dist(0., sd=sigma).logp(x_prev)

        for x in values[1:]:
            sigma = pm.sqrt(alpha_0 + alpha_1 * (x_prev/sigma)**2
                            + beta_1 * sigma**2)
            _logp = _logp + pm.Normal(0., sd=sigma).logp(x)
            x_prev = x

        return _logp
```

To clarify, this is the log-likelihood of the GARCH(1,1) model. The volatility process is a time series where the volatility at time t depends on the residual at time t-1. But to determine the residual at time t-1, we require the volatility at time t-1.

Anyways, that's not really important for my question. What matters is that the likelihood cannot be computed by vectorizing the for-loop (which is how it is done in the link at the top of the post). So you need an explicit loop which at each step first updates the volatility, and then determines likelihood of the observed return.

But the code above doesn't work. If I try to build a model like

```
import numpy as np
returns = np.genfromtxt("SP500.csv")[-200:]
garchmodel = pm.Model()
with garchmodel:
    alpha_0 = pm.Exponential('alpha_0', 30., testval=.02)
    alpha_1 = pm.Uniform('alpha_1', lower=0, upper=1, testval=.9) 
    upper = pm.Deterministic('upper', 1-alpha_1)
    beta_1 = pm.Uniform('beta_1', lower=0, upper=upper, testval=.05)
    sigma_0 = pm.Exponential('sigma_0', 30., testval=.02)

    garch = GARCH('garch', alpha_0=alpha_0, alpha_1=alpha_1, 
                  beta_1=beta_1, sigma_0=sigma_0, observed=returns)
```

The "SP500.csv" file can be found on e.g. [github](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/tree/master/pymc3/examples/data)

This code generate the error:

```
ValueError: length not known
```

I'm pretty certain that this is because the for loops are conflicting with theano. How do I deal with this?

Comment: I don't get any error. Are you sure you have the latest code for theano and pymc3?

Comment: Yea, you're right, I can run the code on a different machine. But my laptop is still throwing errors, even though everything is up to date.

Comment: Have you considered submitting this to the PyMC3 repository. I think it looks like a good example...

Comment: It produced bad results on the datasets that I tested it on. I think it's because of the choice of priors. I didn't investigate it any further -- still can't get it to run on my own laptop.

Comment: But apart from the priors it should be OK to use though.

Comment: I added this to PyMC3 - https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/pull/965

Comment: This is now in PyMC3 - https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/pull/987 and other examples will be added in the future to the Documentation